# Show that $|\,\ddot{\boldsymbol{r}}|$ is constant if $\ddot{\boldsymbol{r}}=\lambda\, \dot{\boldsymbol{r}}\times \boldsymbol{r}$

Tags: vectors

I have shown that $|\,\dot{\boldsymbol{r}}|$ is constant but don't know how to go about showing it for $|\,\ddot{\boldsymbol{r}}|$. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can show that the derivative of $|\ddot{r}| $ is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to skip some details, but here is the general idea / computation for the proof. You should try to justify the missing details and steps, work out the proper Leibniz rules.

For convenience, I'll write $f = |\ddot{\mathbf{r}}|^2$

$|\ddot{\mathbf{r}}|^2 = \ddot{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \ddot{\mathbf{r}}.$

Take the derivative, and you'll get:

$\dot{f} = 2 \dddot{\mathbf{r}}\cdot \ddot{\mathbf{r}} = 2 (\lambda \ddot{\mathbf{r}}\times \mathbf{r}) \cdot (\lambda \dot{\mathbf{r}} \times \mathbf{r}) = 2\lambda^3((\dot{\mathbf{r}}\times \mathbf{r})\times \mathbf{r})\cdot (\dot{\mathbf{r}}\times \mathbf{r})$

The vector $(\dot{\mathbf{r}}\times \mathbf{r})\times \mathbf{r}$ is orthogonal to both $(\dot{\mathbf{r}}\times \mathbf{r})$ and $\mathbf{r}$.

**Note** In general, it is always easier to work with $|v|^2$ than with $|v|$.

Answer (score 1):

take the derivative with respect to time

$$ \dddot r = \lambda \ddot r \times r + \lambda \dot r \times \dot r $$

the second term is 0 since is a vectorial product of a vector by itself

so finally $ \dddot r = \lambda^2 \dot r \times r \times r $ which is again zero

Comment: Am I missing something or does that require the vector product to be associative?

Comment: @TonyK That's not right. $(\dot{r} \times r)$ is a vector that is orthogonal to both $r$ and $\dot{r}$. The only way for $(\dot{r} \times r) \times r$ to be zero is if one of the two vectors are zero.

Comment: @Braindead: Well, I only edited in the cross-product signs! But I agree that this answer is flawed, and I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @TonyK My apologies, I didn't look carefully to see who posted the answer.